# windows 8 mobile apps - Fetching online data and displaying javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm new to windows 8 mobile app development.

I'm customizing a 'Grid App' in Javascript/HTML5 and trying to modify the data.js to fetch data and populate the 'SampleDate' array.

Fetching data from the web feed is done but the problem is as the request is asynchronous the executions proceeds without waiting for the response.

The array always becomes empty but when i try to log the array data to the console it logs properly after fetching.

please give me a solution so that i can populate and view the fetched data.

this is how i changed the default `generateSampleData()` method;

```
WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://www.yamu.lk/feed/" })
       .done(function complete(result) {

           console.log(result.responseXML);
           var items = result.responseXML.querySelectorAll("item");
           for (var n = 0; n < items.length; n++) {
               sampleItems[n] = { group: sampleGroups[0], title: items[n].querySelector("title").textContent, subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 1", description: items[n].querySelector("description").textContent, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: lightGray };
               console.log(items[n].querySelector("title").textContent);

           }


           },
           function error(error) {

           },
           function progress(result) {

           });

        return sampleItems;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from the fact that your ListView isn't being bound to the sampleItems array directly, it's being bound to a binding list that is having the sampleItems pushed onto it. Check out line 12 of data.js:

```
 generateSampleData().forEach(function (item) {
    list.push(item);
});
```

What you want to do is wait to push your data into the binding list until it's been retrieved from the web service. One way to do that is to have the generateSampleData() function return the WinJS.xhr promise instead of the sampleItems array. So generateSampleData() becomes:

```
return WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://www.yamu.lk/feed/" });
```

and line 12 becomes:

```
generateSampleData().done(function complete(result) {
       console.log(result.responseXML);
       var items = result.responseXML.querySelectorAll("item");
       for (var n = 0; n < items.length; n++) {
           list.push({ group: sampleGroups[0], title: items[n].querySelector("title").textContent, subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 1", description: items[n].querySelector("description").textContent, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: lightGray });
           console.log(items[n].querySelector("title").textContent);
       }});
```

Or something along those lines.

Definitely check out how [binding lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700774.aspx) work for more info.

Answer (score 0):

1) Declare a global varible like *IsWaitingForData*.

2) Before send the request set value to True;

3) In done function when data redy set the varible to false;

4) Use array.

You should read about promises in JavaScript: [Link](http://dev.bennage.com/blog/2012/08/21/winjs-unpacking-promises/)

Here is article about Asynchronous programming: [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700330.aspx)

Here is good article about promises: [Link](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/07/19/want-to-build-win8winjs-apps-you-need-to-understand-promises/)

```
var promises=WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://www.yamu.lk/feed/" });
WinJS.Promise.join(promises).then(function () {
        //do something with array
    });
```

Comment: how to access the response data? i need to read the xml data in that URL. please help